# VirtualBox image z RPI

Tags: pi-2, virtualization

How can I convert rpi image to:

1. Virtualbox image
2. i386 live CD
3. amd64 live CD
4. i386 install CD
5. amd64 install CD

Comment: I'm somewhat confused as to what you are asking here. The Disc Image Files for the Pi have to be written to the SD card in a very specific way. Converting it to an amd64 install file (assuming you could) isn't going to do anything. If you are looking to run Linux as a virtual machine on another computer that's relatively simple to do.

Comment: You really should explain *why* you need to do this.  Unless you want a GUI exactly like the default used on Raspbian, using "Debian 9 stretch" is going to be pretty identical to using "Raspbian 9 stretch".  WRT to the GUI, the source code should be around, and I believe I read here one day that the Foundation had an x86(-64) package (although I could not find in it Debian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Virtualbox image

Realistically you can't, VirtualBox is for x86(-64) [ISAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) only, whereas Pi oriented images are ARM based.

You would have to take the source code for everything in the base image and recompile it -- which is not realistic.

You could take stock Debian and tweak it in the same ways as Raspbian does.  There are probably a few things in Rasbpian that are unique to it, but they could be compiled from source.  This would be much less work than the last option, but still considerable -- possibly hundreds of person hours.

> 2. i386 live CD
> 3. amd64 live CD
> 4. i386 install CD
> 5. amd64 install CD

You can't, for the same reason as above.

Comment: `qemu` may be worth a look for ARM-VMs...

Comment: Yeah I think there is an actual Pi kernel emulation for that if you dig; probably some mention of such in the Q&A's here tagged `qemu`: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bqemu%5D+is%3Aquestion